# psql hard disk usage

Tags: postgresql

I was copying data from one table to another table in my PSQL  database and I got a full disk space error. After checking the number of rows inserted into the destination table, I recognized that no rows have been added to it. The problem is here: No rows have been added to the destination table but I have no remained space after that error. I wanted to know that if there is some temp space in PLSQ and they are keeping rows there? And if there is, how can I free that space to get my free space back?

Comment: Dead rows are still in the table, check pg_stat_user_tables. If that table looks empty, you can use TRUNCATE to get rid of all garbage as well.

Comment: dump target table, then drop and restore.

Answer (score 2):

An out-of-space condition will terminate the statement, but the ensuing rollback will not remove data from the target table.

I would `DROP` or `TRUNCATE` the target table to reclaim space.

Comment: if I truncate the target table, my previous data will be removed too. Are there any possible ways to remove those dead rows without truncating the whole table?

Comment: Export the data with `pg_dump` and restore them to the truncated table.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is most likely bloated. Run a [`VACUUM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-vacuum.html) and check the disk usage again:

```
VACUUM table_name
```

You might also wanna check if the table size as well:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('table_name'));
```

Comment: `VACUUM (FULL)` requires extra space to finish.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for pointing out. I oversaw that the op disk is actually full :)